# Nodes or set of nodes connected to a subgraph networkx

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

I have 2 graphs *A* and *B*. *B* is a strongly connected subgraph of *A*. **I want to find the node(s) in *A* that have a path to any of the nodes in *B*.** How do I do this in Networkx?

**NB:** I have already tried using weakly connected components but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `B` is strongly connected, then if you choose any node `u` in `B`, then if some node `x` in `A` has a path to some node `b` in `B`, then there is a path from `x` to `u` (there is a path from `b` to `u` because `B` is strongly connected and then the `x` to `b` to `u` path exists).  So having a path to any node in `B` is the same thing as having a path to one specific node in `B`.  Let `X` be the set of nodes with a path to `u`.  This is the set you want.

If you do `X = nx.ancestors(A, u)` then `X` is the set of nodes with a path to `u`.  If you want the subgraph itself, then do `G = A.subgraph(X)`, but if you just want the set of nodes, then it's `X`.

---

Note - this is effectively [the algorithm](https://epidemicsonnetworks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions/EoN.estimate_SIR_prob_size_from_dir_perc.html#EoN.estimate_SIR_prob_size_from_dir_perc) used in the Epidemics on Networks package https://epidemicsonnetworks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ (which I wrote) for estimating the probability of an epidemic using directed percolation.

Comment: nx.ancestors(A,u) works flawlessly. However, it takes a single node **u** in **B** and returns all nodes in **A** that have a path to **u**. This is going to be inefficient if I have to check for all nodes in *B* for a very large graph. How can this be optimized?

Comment: All you need to do is do this for one node.  I tried to explain in the main answer a bit, but because `B` is strongly-connected, you can be sure that if `u` and `v` are in `B` then anything with a path to `u` also has a path to `v` and vice versa (because `u` and `v` have paths to each other).  So if you find all the ancestors for `u`, you've also got all the ancestors for `v` and vice versa.